# Change default boot from Windows to Linux

Tags: linux, windows, grub2, dual-boot

I have a system that shipped with Windows 10. I installed Rocky 8.5 on it. When the system boots it defaults to Windows 10. I can boot to Rocky if I press F7 on boot. How would I go about changing it so by default the system boots to Rocky Linux?

Comment: According to your description I assume you have boot entries entered in your UEFI BIOS. If F7 is a boot menu, then most probably F2 is a BIOS setup key. Find boot order in your BIOS setup and move your Rocky Linux above Windows.

Comment: Windows and Linux on one drive? You need to use GRUB.